# Steel basement columns have rusted and split open

Tags: basement, column

[image]

I have basement columns that have rusted and split open. Do you think I need replace them? Thanks!

Thanks a lot for the quick answer, there are five columns in my basement and three of them had split open. the other two had little rust. basement is dry and no crackles on the floor at all. Seems to me it is the concrete inside the column attract some moisture and the column start rust from inside first. I think I need have someone replace at least three of them.Anyone have idea how much it cost? Also since those columns support the beam.I am little worried if the new column install little different. will the upstairs wall crack little bit since the shape of the support beam may change little bit?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of variables... one of the most important is what load they are supporting and how badly are they rusted aside from the split. Unless you are in a position to accurately gauge their "importance" to the structure you really should consult a qualified contractor.  From the look of the photo there appears to be some buckling where the seam has split which seems very unusual to me and cause for concern.  The good news is that if everything else is OK, it's a pretty simple and inexpensive repair.

Comment: Simple, inexpensive, and worrying: sounds like time to repair it.

Comment: @paddy  Not really, for one thing I have no idea where you are or what the structural conditions we discussed are.  If it's just a matter of swapping out the columns, I'd say a couple hours apiece at the prevailing rate where you are, plus the cost of materials.